# Setting Multiple value from array using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch some results from an api which display results from the provided day as name &  some text, I need to set state of the results received for the first 5 values for that i am using slice method , my issue is after setting state I can see only last fetched array value is updated on the ui how can I add all 5 values attaching the code I am trying below ..

```js
const [fact, setfact] = useState("")
let d = new Date()


let facturl = `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/feed/onthisday/births/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}`
fetch(facturl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {


    data.births.slice(0, 5).map((x) => {

      return setfact(x.text + x.year)
    })
  });
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want `fact` to be an array of values? (Also, that's generally not how `.map` should be used)

Comment: hmmm  m not sure it needs to be an array or not but i need setfact to set all  5 array returned results on an paragraph tag

Answer (score 0):

You can store facts to state, and loop during rendering.

```
const [facts, setFacts] = useState([])
let date = new Date()
let facturl = `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/feed/onthisday/births/${date.getMonth()+1}/${date.getDate()}`
 fetch(facturl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setFacts(data.births.slice(0, 5))
      });
```

Rendering:

```
return (
 facts.map((fact) =>
  <li key={fact.text}>
    {fact.text}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: thanks for replyng but it didnt work , i got the following error ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {text, pages, year}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: you have to use map in order to render array

Answer (score 0):

do fetch inside useEffect,than setFacts and then map, fact should be [] and not string

Comment: currently  m using fetch inside use effect only

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are overwriting the state and storing only the last value of the iteration, you can instead create an array and store it in state and map over it to render

```js
const [facts, setfacts] = useState([])
let d = new Date()


let facturl = `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/feed/onthisday/births/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}`
fetch(facturl)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {


    const facts = data.births.slice(0, 5).map((x) => {

      return x.text + x.year;
    });
    setFacts(facts);
  });


  return (
       <div className="facts">
            {facts.map(fact=> (<div className="fact-item">{fact}</div>))}
       </div>
  )
```

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: Hi dear Shubham, Apologize me because of this mention, I sent a question post to SO, and really your idea is very important to me, if it is possible, please review it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66863592/6877799